# Wildcards inside quotes in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, automation, wmic

First post so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question!

I am trying to write a batch script to uninstall all old versions of a program and then install the new version. Problem is there are many old versions across our environment, too many to count. The following batch:

```
wmic product where name=”XYZ Version 2” call uninstall /nointeractive
```

Uninstalls the program successfully. But the problem is the computer could have Version 1, Version 2, Version 3, Version 4, etc. I tried the following:

```
wmic product where name="XYZ Ver*" call uninstall
```

But this returns an error "No Instance(s) Available. Where am I going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: From a batch file: `WMIC Product Where "Name Like 'XYZ Ver%%'" Call Uninstall` BTW, I'm not aware that the Uninstall Method accepts any parameters, _I would assume `/NoInteractive` is just not flagged as an issue_.

Comment: WMIC uses a dialect of SQL called WQL. Wildcards are different. `%` = any number of characters and `_` is a single characters. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wql-operators and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/like-operator

Comment: Note that doubling the '%' character in Compo's comment is required in order to get a single '%' character.